# Haskell, doing some code followed by an if statement in one function

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've been using haskell for roughly a week now and I don't seem to understand how to add a line of code above an if statement that will be executed each time the function is called. Below is the code I've put together for the purpose of this question:

```
let example x = 
    if (x == 1) then "Number is 1" 
    else if (even x) then example (x - 1) 
    else example (x - 2)
```

What I want to happen is for the number to be printed each time the function is called, so logic was telling me to find out how to add a line above the if statement to print [x]. I've looked into it heavily but haven't been able to find a solution. I looked into the "Do" but I couldn't seem to get it working. If anyone can shine some light on this area it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried with `do`? Because that's a correct way.

Comment: I know that works, what i want to happen is each iteration of this it prints the number. As it stands you call it and it just returns "Number is 1" instead of (The number you've input) and then "Number is 1"

Comment: There is no "if statement" in Haskell, because there are no statements, because everthing (each part of a program) is an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to print something to the screen, your function has to be an `IO` action, so to start with it needs a type signature indicating that.  Next, to perform a series of `IO` actions inside your function, you should use the `do` syntax, but this means to return a value from it you need to use the `return` function:

```
example :: Int -> IO String
example x = do
    putStrLn $ "Calling: example " ++ show x
    if x == 1
        then return "Number is 1"
        else if even x
            then example (x - 1)
            else example (x - 2)
```

You don't need the `return` on `example (x - 1)` or `example (x - 2)` because the type of these expressions is `IO String`, it's already the type needed for the return value of this function.  However, `"Number is 1"` just has type `String`.  To turn it into `IO String`, you have to use the `return` function.

Comment: Thanks for your response bheklilr. The way it works at the moment it already displays "Number is 1" without me having to import IO String. Is there no way to add one line above the current code to allow it to print x each time instead of having to import ?

Comment: @Jordan Your function is returning the value `"Number is 1"`, and in GHCi that value will be printed out after evaluation.  If you type in `1 + 2`, GHCi will print `3`, but the function itself is not printing the value `3`, only returning it.  If you tried to make an executable using this function, it would not print out `"Number is 1"` without a `putStrLn` call somewhere.  If you want to print to the screen in Haskell, you have to use `IO`, there is no other way.  Alternatively you could return a list of strings that are later printed, but that is more complex and I doubt it is what you want.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for that. Sorry if it seemed a bit simple, but i'd rather learn how something works than the answer just being given. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jordan No question is too simple, but there can be bad questions.  You seem to be putting forth the effort to understand, all the pieces just haven't fallen into place yet.  Haskell can be pretty daunting at first, but it's worth the effort to learn.  The IO model is quite unique so it takes time to get used to, but it's rewarding once you understand it.  Just keep practicing and some day you'll be answering my questions on stackoverflow =)

Comment: Strictly speaking I think saying that it needs a "type signature/annotation" indicating IO is untrue -- it needs such a type, right. :)

Comment: @Sarah Technically you don't have to provide a type signature for most functions in Haskell, the compiler can infer it instead.  Without a signature you can encounter strange behavior, for example this function could also work with `Integer` instead of `Int`, but `Integer` has different runtime behavior than `Int` does. The compiler would have defaulted to using `Integer` in this case (with a warning), so the type signature I used is different than what would be inferred. It's always preferable to give an explicit signature, so I pretend that it's required with the `-Wall -Werror` flags to GHC

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an `IO ()` and you can use `do` notation e.g.

```
example :: Int -> IO ()
example x = do
  putStrLn $ "Number is " ++ (show x)
  case x of
    1 -> return ()
    _ -> if (even x) then example (x-1) else example(x-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `trace` function. It does specifically what you are looking for. And the function's signature need not be changed.

```
import Debug.Trace

example x = trace ("Called with " ++ (show x)) $
    if (x == 1) then "Number is 1" 
    else if (even x) then example (x - 1) 
    else example (x - 2)
```

[Documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) for `trace`.